# How two phase commit is working in atomic transaction?

Tags: web-services, security, soap, soap-client

I have some queries in two phase commit protocol,

1.What will it do on the failure of second phase commit?

2.How it maintains the fault tolerance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers from [Two-phase commit protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol).

> What will it do on the failure of second phase commit?

Failure of the commit phase is handled as follows:

> If any cohort votes No during the commit-request phase (or the coordinator's timeout expires):
>
> 1. The coordinator sends a rollback message to all the cohorts.
> 2. Each cohort undoes the transaction using the undo log, and releases
>      the resources and locks held during the transaction.
> 3. Each cohort
>      sends an acknowledgement to the coordinator.
> 4. The coordinator undoes
>          the transaction when all acknowledgements have been received.

---

> How it maintains the fault tolerance?

In many cases it does not, and may need human intervention:

> it is not resilient to all possible failure configurations, and in rare cases user (e.g., a system's administrator) intervention is needed to remedy an outcome. To accommodate recovery from failure (automatic in most cases) the protocol's participants use logging of the protocol's states. Log records, which are typically slow to generate but survive failures, are used by the protocol's recovery procedures. Many protocol variants exist that primarily differ in logging strategies and recovery mechanisms. Though usually intended to be used infrequently, recovery procedures compose a substantial portion of the protocol, due to many possible failure scenarios to be considered and supported by the protocol.

Comment: thanks for the reply..rollback means, Is the request will send again?

Comment: It means that the transaction is aborted. It can be retried by the application, but it would not automatically do this.